# unknown sources turns back on about every 24 hours

Tags: malware, unknown-sources

I'm having to turn off unknown sources everyday. I'm on 5.1. Not rooted. Never installed anything except from app store. Eset Av says phone clean. Root checker says not rooted. 
Had phone from new. Bush/archos b2. 
An app called My Apps appears daily too.
It isn't in my account on play store.
Not sure if it appears in apps/downloads. I'll check when it next appears.
Malware? Bloatware?
Anyone seen this?

Comment: Probably a security feature. There may be some xposed module for this, but you would have to be rooted for it to work.

Comment: This is happening to me, too. New blue energy mini android 5.1. Did u get a solution?

Comment: There might be some 3rd party app that's downloading that `my app` try finding that out! Also It's not a big problem to leave unknown resources ticked on (unless you install completely unsafe apps) but if you want it to be switched off really bad try factory resetting your phone. Good luck!